# How to Deploy .Net 6.0 Web API in IIS Server

Tags: .net, iis-7

I have deploy .Net Framework 5.0 in Windows Server.It works fine .Today I have migrated .Net Framework 6.0.The applicaton works fine when I use in Local Environment (localhost) but its not working when I deploy in Windows Server.Please check the below screenshot and installed runtime details.Please advise how to deploy ..

Screenshot:-
[image]

Installed Runtime : -

dotnet-hosting-6.0.6-win.exe

Comment: 1) have checked the port number? maybe the site you created is under a different port

2) Are you sure you are accessing the correct site? Maybe you created the site under the default site. A 404 is expected unless you have a default route.

Comment: Please check video screencast for your reference. https://www.screencast.com/t/QDMK3CRu3gLm

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 401 error.